# How to use the host IP as the connection to an external server in a docker container?

Tags: sql-server, docker, networking, redhat, docker-network

I have a docker container running on a Redhat 9 server. The Redhat IP address has been granted access to a SQL Server database in our private network. But the docker container cannot access the SQL Server, I imagine because it has a different IP address.

I need the docker container to somehow use the IP of the Redhat 9 server to connect to the SQL Server because the docker container with its unique IP cannot connect to the SQL Server.

How would one go about configuring this in docker?

Comment: Have you assigned routable IP address(es) to your Docker containers? Typically Docker assigns IP addresses to containers from the non-routable 172.16.0.0/12 CIDR block and all internet<->container traffic gets routed through the Docker host's own IP address. If, however, you've allocated specific routable IP addresses to your containers (i.e.: something from your organisation's own routable address pool) then the containers will be communicating with their own IP address.

Comment: If (with `jq` installed) you issue `docker container inspect YourContainerIdHere | jq '.[].NetworkSettings.Networks'` what addresses do the `Gateway` and `IPAddress` properties hold? If they're not 172.16.0.0/12 addresses you will probably need to register the `IPAddress` value.

Comment: Docker uses an internal NAT setup, and other hosts are completely unaware of the Docker-internal IP addresses.  The `docker inspect` IP address will be unreachable from the network (even to send TCP response packets) and it shouldn't be relevant here.  I'd expect the remote database server would see the host's IP address in the IP packet headers, and it has no way to tell the request came from a container.